# Dell 11 3000 - Sound for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Audio Drivers?

Tags: drivers, sound, speakers

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a USB Flash Drive.  Booting in Demo Mode seems work Ok in a Dell 11 3000.  Microphone input works well, however Audio Output does not. (Tested). I imagine the audio drivers need to be updated.

Appreciate any help.

The configuration of the Dell 11 3000 is:

```
sudo lshw -class multimedia
    *-multimedia            
        description: Audio device
        product: ValleyView High Definition Audio Controller
        vendor: Intel Corporation
        physical id: 1b
        bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
        version: 0e
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
        configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
        resources: irq:106 memory:90710000-90713fff
```

Comment: Additional Information:  The Audio works through the Audio Connector, the Internal Microphone also seems to work, however the built in speakers do not work.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I have the same Dell 11 3000 series computer, with the same configuration output you display above.  I had the same problem with speakers not working when I was running Ubuntu Live from the USB (though the headphones did work).  Once I installed Ubuntu (alongside Windows 8.1) the speakers worked fine without me having to do anything.